# RxPy - Why are emissions interleaved with merging operators?

Tags: python, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-py

So I'm learning RxPy after doing RxJava and RxKotlin for two years. One thing I'm noticing is that certain operators cause crazy interleaving that does not happen in RxJava.

For example, `flat_map()` will cause emissions to interleave out of order for a simple `Observable` source.

```
items = Observable.from_( ("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Epsilon"))

items.flat_map(lambda s: Observable.from_(list(s))).subscribe(print)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A
l
B
p
e
G
h
t
a
D
a
a
m
e
E
m
l
p
a
t
s
a
i
l
o
n
```

However, with RxJava or RxKotlin, everything stays sequential and in order.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Observable.just("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Epsilon")
        .flatMap {
            Observable.from(it.toCharArray().asIterable())
        }.subscribe(::println)
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A
l
p
h
a
B
e
t
a
G
a
m
m
a
D
e
l
t
a
E
p
s
i
l
o
n
```

I confirmed that everything is running on the `MainThread` and there is no weird asynchronous scheduling going on (I think).

Why does RxPy behave this way? I notice that this happens almost with any operator that deals with multiple `Observable` sources merging together. What exactly is the default Scheduler doing?

Also, why is there no `concat_map()` in RxPy? I'm getting the impression this is somehow not possible with how the scheduling works...

Comment: The fact that `flatMap` happens to respect order in RxJava is an implementation detail, and you should not be relying on it. Use `concatMap` if you require order to be preserved.

Comment: Well sure, I guess that's true. I guess that evolves my question to why is `concat_map()` not implemented in RxPy? Will update question to include this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has already been noted,  `flatMap` does not guarantee order. RxPy doesn't implement `concat_map` as a distinct operator but you can get the same effect using the `map` and `concat_all` operators

```
Observable.from_( ("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Epsilon"))\
          .map(lambda s: Observable.from_(list(s)))\
          .concat_all()\
          .subscribe(print)
```